# .htaccess rewrite rule from mydomain.com/contact.htm to mydomain.com/contact

Tags: .htaccess

I guess this was a very common and simple `.htaccess` rewrite rule, however I wasn't able to google a solution for it.

So, the question is in the title already, how can I rewrite the address to change it from `example.com/contact.htm` to `example.com/contact`? The rule would of course not be only for just the `contact.htm` but for any page in the website. No need to worry about GET variables, since I won't be using any.

[ Also, do you think this is or might be considered a good practice or not really relevant? ]

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, do you just want `/contact` to serve `/contact.htm` or do you want someone visiting `/contact.htm` to get redirected to `/contact` but then get served `/contact.htm` anyway?

Comment: I want /contact to server /contact.htm. That's right.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact.htm$ /contact
```

This should serve `contact.html` when requesting `example.com/contact/`

Comment: That's the opposite of what is asked for.

Comment: You want it to serve /contact the request is /contact.html? Then write it like i did on the last edit.

Comment: I have tried that, but I can't access any page on my website, not even index.php for instance, and I am getting  a 500 internal server error on every request. Note I am using WAMP for local testing and have just created a plain text file with no extension named ".htaccess". Don't know if there's something wrong with that... Thanks again and would appreciate further instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using MultiViews. You'll need to load the [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) module and turn MultiViews on, then Apache will automatically look for a file with an extension (there's a priority list in case you have both `.html` and `.htm` files with the same name for instance).